# Django app_label is wrong on models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django DRF application. Here is my project structure.

```
myproject/
    myproject/
    apps/
        myApp1/
            __init__.py
            apps.py
            admin.py
            models.py
            urls.py
            views.py
        myApp2/
        __init__.py
    static/
    manage.py
```

and my`INSTALLED_APPS` contains:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apps.myApp1.apps.AppOneConfig',
    'apps.myApp2.apps.AppTwoConfig',
]
```

When I went to `./manage.py shell_plus` and run:

```
SomeModel._meta.label
```

I see `myApp1` or `myApp2` instead of `apps.myApp1` && `apps.myApp2`. And even in migrations Models are referred as `myApp1.Model` or `myApp2.Model` not as `apps.myApp1.Model` or `apps.myApp2.Model`

Also, specified `AppConfig`.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppOneConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.myApp1'
    verbose_name = 'My App One'
```

Is that expected ? I am pretty new to Django. Can anyone suggest what the mistake was?

Comment: Yes that is expected. You can however add an `AppConfig` and specify a different label.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oops. My bad, I did that. forgot to mention. Updating my question.

Answer (score 2):

> Is that expected?

**Yes**, that is expected. By default, the app label uses the last part of the "python path". You can change it by specifying this in the [**`AppConfig`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig). It is the [**`.label`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label) of this `AppConfig` that determines the app label, and:

> (…) It **defaults to the last component of `name`**. It should be a valid Python identifier. (…)

Now the [**`.name`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name), and this is:

> **Full Python path to the application**, e.g. `'django.contrib.admin'`.

You can specify this by first specifying the `AppConfig` in the `__init__.py` file of your `myApp1` directory:

```
# apps/myApp/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'apps.myApp.apps.App1Config'
```

then you make a file `apps.py` in the `myApp1` directory, and write:

```
# apps/myApp/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class App1Config(AppConfig):
    label = 'apps_myapp1'
```

> **Note**: normally directories use `slug_case`, so I think it might be better to rename your `myApp1` to `myapp1` or `my_app1`.

**EDIT**: You thus need to set the `label` attribute of your `AppOneConfig` to:

```
class AppOneConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.myApp1'
    label = 'apps_myapp1'
    verbose_name = 'My App One'
```